Why does current lag behind voltage by 90° in an inductive circuit?
We can easily prove this with KVL, a little bit calculus, and trigonometry.
We get voltage as a sine function and current as a cosine function. Then we apply 'Add sugar to coffee' and get that current lags behind voltage by 90°.
But why don't we say that it leads by 270°?
Is this just convention or is there any intuitive explanation for this? Would our equations stop working if we suppose it led by 270°?

Smaller numbers are just easier to work with

$270^{\circ}=-90^{\circ} \mod 360^{\circ}$.

Because in a periodic sine function a phase of +90° is identical to a phase of -270°. You usually take the smallest value.
